# Typescript: object with at least one property of type T

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I write `HasNumber` without typescript giving me an error because on `HasNumberAndString` name is not a `number`? I want a way to enforce `HasNumberAndString` to have at least one property of type `number` (without enforcing the property name), but be allowed to have properties of other types as well. Is this possible?

```
interface HasNumber {
    [key: string]: number;
}

interface HasNumberAndString extends HasNumber {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

There is no great way in TypeScript to allow a type with an index signature to have an additional property that doesn't match the index signature type.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for the suggestion to allow exceptions to index signatures, and maybe give it a  to show support for it. For now, though, it's not directly supported.

---

One workaround is to use a [type intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) instead of extending an interface:

```
type SortaHasNumberAndString = { [key: string]: number } & { age: number, name: string };
```

You're basically trying to fool the compiler since technically this means that the `name` property should be both of type `string` and `number`, but you're hoping the compiler only notices the `string` part.  This actually does work when reading properties from a value of that type:

```
declare const sortaHasNumberAndString: SortaHasNumberAndString;
sortaHasNumberAndString.name; // string, not number
sortaHasNumberAndString.age; // number
sortaHasNumberAndString.numberOfLimbs; // number due to index signature
```

But doesn't work well when trying to assign to a value of that type:

```
// error, complains that name is not string & number
const notSoGreat: SortaHasNumberAndString = {
  name: "Long John Silver",
  age: 43,
  numberOfLimbs: 3
}
```

So you're forced to use something like assertions or other tricks:

```
const notSoGreat = {
  name: "Long John Silver",
  age: 43,
  numberOfLimbs: 3
} as any as SortaHasNumberAndString; // okay now
```

And that means you run into trouble with functions accepting this type:

```
declare function acceptSortaHasNumberAndString(x: SortaHasNumberAndString): void;
acceptSortaHasNumberAndString({name: "a", age: 123}); // error!
```

Not ideal.

---

Another solution (the better one in my opinion) is to allow `HasNumber` and `HasNumberAndString` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the key with a number property.  This means that there is no index signature to worry about.

```
type HasNumber<K extends keyof any> = Record<K, number>;
type HasNumberAndString<K extends keyof any> = { name: string } & HasNumber<Exclude<K, "name">>;
```

This uses the built-in [`Record`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1379-L1384) and [`Exclude`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386-L1389) type aliases to say that `HasNumberAndString<K>` should have a `name` property of type `string`, but all other properties should be of type `number`.  You can modify those to reflect different constraints if you need to.  Let's see how it works:

If you want to talk about a specific value of type `HasNumberAndString` you need to specify the keys in the type:

```
const hns: HasNumberAndString<'age'> = {
  name: "Harry James Potter",
  age: 38
}
```

That might not be great, but in most cases you can just let TypeScript infer those keys for you:

```
const inferHasNumberAndString = 
  <T>(x: T & HasNumberAndString<keyof T>): HasNumberAndString<keyof T> => x;

const hns = inferHasNumberAndString({
  name: "Harry James Potter",
  age: 38
}); // inferred as type HasNumberAndString<"name" | "age">;
```

The above helper function `inferHasNumberAndString` is generic and shows the general method by which you can accept values of type `HasNumberAndString<K>` without enforcing `K` yourself:

```
declare function acceptHasNumberAndString<T>(x: T & HasNumberAndString<keyof T>): void;
acceptHasNumberAndString({ name: "Hermione Granger", age: 39 });
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!