# Allowing a different Typescript type for one property

Tags: typescript

## The Issue.

I'm wanting to create an interface that allows for a string key value pair for any string you want. I can do this already with:

```js
export interface QueryParams extends Record<string, string> {};
```

But let's say I want the `user` key to be an object.

### Attempt 1

If I try to do something like this:

```js
export type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

export interface QueryParameters extends Record<string, string | number> {
  user?: User;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'user' of type 'User' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
```

### Attempt 2

I've also tried doing:

```js
export interface QueryParameters {
  user?: User;
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

But I get the same error.

I could extend `Record<string, string | User>` but I only want the user key to be able to be a `User`, not any other key.

## Question

How can I make the `user` key be of type `User` while allowing all other possible keys to be a string?

Comment: Short answer, you can't easily have an indexed type where some properties don't match that indexed type. Long answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056494/typescript-object-with-at-least-one-property-of-type-t