# How to type a T object with at least one property like K?

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this:

```
function flatten(tree, property) {
    // ... implementation
    return tree[property];s
}
```

I would like to restrict types of arguments with TypeScript so that it would be generic and fit the type like this:

```
type Tree = {
    subTree: Tree;
    name: string;
}
```

e.g.

```
function flatten(tree: Tree, property: 'subTree'): Tree {
    // ... implementation
    return tree[property];
}
```

But with generics:

```
function flatten<T, K>(tree: T, property: K): T {
    return tree[property];
}
```

The above of course doesn't work

I looked at this [Typescript: object with at least one property of type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056494/typescript-object-with-at-least-one-property-of-type-t) but it's not what I want

I would like to restrict type `T` so it has at least one property named `K` of type `T`

[ts sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThaBeKBvAUFLUDOBXAI3kQC5YEIBuTbAOwEMBbCMnYOAS1oHNqBfdOgBmeWgGNgHAPa0oQgDb1gwCLQA8MADRQA0gD4AFO1KxtYOFMhxQZHQEoyMNDSwJgeOLOMQA2ucsQ1iAAuvzoQA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB4akW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Konrad - Slightly tangential, but: How would you create a `Tree` object? It seems like it would have a chicken-and-egg problem. I'm asking because I suspect I'm missing something a bit obvious... :-) Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in reality this type looks more like `type Tree = { subTree?: Tree[], name: string }` I just didn't want to complicate things. Although, it's kind of not working when I changed the types https://tsplay.dev/mbKgBW

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I played around and it works fine now https://tsplay.dev/mbKgBW 
Thank you for noticing the potential issue

Comment: Your last fix doesn't work; I'd do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOxMlN).  But that's outside the scope of the question as asked so I'm going to ignore that for now

Comment: @jcalz I've pasted the wrong link https://tsplay.dev/m33O3m Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @Konrad - *"...in reality this type looks more like..."* Ah, okay, that makes sense. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write recursive [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), so you should make sure that `property` is of a generic type `K` constrained to a keylike type ([the `PropertyKey` utility type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7c220232f2a91bf37df03d47e86ae2b0f11fdd4f/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L107) is just an alias for `string | number | symbol`), and that `tree` is of a generic type `T` constrained to `Record<K, T>` ([the `Record<K, T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is just an alias for a simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) saying a type with properties of type `T` at the keys of type `K`):

```
function flatten<T extends Record<K, T>, K extends PropertyKey>(tree: T, property: K): T {
    return tree[property];
}
```

That compiles with no error.  Let's test it on your example structure:

```
type Tree = {
    subTree: Tree;
    name: string;
}
declare const tree: Tree;
flatten(tree, "subTree"); // okay
flatten(tree, "name"); // error
```

Looks good. If you pass in `"name"` as the `property`, then `tree` is not a valid structure (since `tree.name` is not of the same type as `tree`), but if you pass in `"subTree"` then everything is fine.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANgQylApmAPAFUSwA9swATAZ0QCUsI4Anc3AaQBpF8A+T1o0jiqIACozgAHLIygBPVllncAFFEZYsALi6cJ4qTNnbWASm2EA3gChEtxOqghGSNRoDaeydLkBdANxWAL5WVnJSXOpYiAC8iNZ2iJQgAEb4keaRAQlgaAC2WolqMGAA5gHB5PTo6ogMYJRQiK4FaRoBqBhkqpGcAERJqZG9Jn6IAPRjiHAA1miyVh2YON0afTn5w6MTRIzijEA)